# Fuzzy lookup for two different data tables in r by using stringdist_left_Join

Tags: r

Getting below mentioned error

```
> Error in stringdist::stringdist(v1, v2, method = method, ...) :   
> unused argument (distance_col = "dist")
```

while running this:

```
stringdist_left_join(data1, data2, by = "ADDRESS", max_dist = 0.50, ignore_case = FALSE, method = "jw",distance_col ="dist")
```

Without `distance_col ="dist"` i can run and got output without matching score

So,I need matching score of `ADDRESS` column of `data1` and `data2` through the `distance_col="dist"` variable.

Pls help me to get the matching score

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error using the same `stringdist_left_join` call you provided and sample data (`fuzzyjoin` v0.1.2 & `stringdist` v0.9.4.4).  Please provide the structure of your data

Comment: a<- data.frame(name = c('Ace Co', 'Bayes', 'asd', 'Bcy', 'Baes', 'Bays'),price = c(10, 13, 2, 1, 15, 1))
b <- data.frame(name = c('Ace Co.', 'Bayes Inc.', 'asdf'),qty = c(9, 99, 10))
stringdist_left_join(a, b, by = "name", max_dist = 0.3, ignore_case = FALSE, method = "jw",distance_col = "dist")

Comment: using that data and your `stringdist_left_join` call (switching `a` & `b` in for `data1` &`data2`). i am unable to reproduce your error

Comment: Sorry i don't know,how to do the alignment in comment box. Are you getting the sample data?

Comment: yes, try updating your packages or restarting your R session.  I have been unable to reproduce your error in a fresh R session with the package versions specified in my first comment

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Pls check this link and (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44381219/8118041) see answered by Arthur Yip. He got the score for the same sample data. I actually took sample from his answer