# How to parse human names in R

Tags: r, parsing, human-readable

I have a large csv with a field of names for example:

```
names <- c("John Smith", "J. Smith", "Sarah Jones", "Nielson, Dave")
```

I also have another list with specific, 'known' names. This list is smaller than the first list because it only holds 1 variation of each name. I want to try and match my names to this list.

So if my list has John Smith, J.Smith and John Smith would be grouped together. The 'key' list if it had Dave Nielson would then group with "Nielson, Dave" for example.

I tried using the humaniformat package, but wasn't really sure how to carry it out.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405895/how-can-i-match-fuzzy-match-strings-from-two-datasets