# How do I do one fuzzy and one exact match in a dataframe?

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I want to be able to fuzzy match one column and exact match another column.

Say I df1 looks like this:

[image]

And df2 looks like this:

[image]

I want to fuzzy match the "Name" but exact match the "Year." So "Ashley" and "Ashlee" would be a match. This is what I have so far:

```
res <- fuzzy_left_join(
  df,
  df2,
  by=c("Year","Name"),
  list(`==`, function(x,y) stringdist(tolower(x), tolower(y), method="lv") <= 3)
)
res %>% 
  select(Year = Year.x, everything(), - Year.y)
```

It appears to be over-matching, though. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: I'm using the fuzzyjoin package.

Comment: ok, thanks. You should include this info when you ask a question (for instance by adding to your code `library(fuzzyjoin)`. Otherwise, people who aren't familiar with the package can't guess and can't help you

Comment: That said, I just realized that you had tagged it with [fuzzyjoin]. So I could have guessed :P

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `fuzzy_join()`, there is the argument `match_fun` which allows you to give a matching function. If the default is over-matching compared to the outcome you want to get, I guess you can play with that argument until you get the matching you want

Comment: If you provide some sample data (not with a picture but in a way that can be replicated), people can try to help you

Comment: An alternative approach, if using `match_fun` is not easy, would be to transform your `Name` column in `df2` with `gsub()` and a regexp, then use `dplyr::left_join()`. If you provide some sample data, I'll be happy to do that

Comment: Actually, I think that you are already using `match_fun` with: `list('==', function(x,y) stringdist(tolower(x), tolower(y), method="lv") <= 3`. So this is what you want to play with until you get the proper matching. I don't know what `method="lv"` is, so personally I would do it with `gsub()`.

Comment: did you solve your fuzzyjoin problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on the right track (hard to tell without your data or you showing us your result!)

The fuzzyjoin will provide all answers with string distance <=3, which may be the "overmatching" you describe.

You can use
`%>% group_by(Year,Name) %>% slice_min(dist)`
to get the best answer according to distance.