# Fuzzy matching string in python pyspark for dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, fuzzy-comparison

I am doing a fuzzy similarity matching  between all rows in 'name' column using python pyspark in Jupyter notebook. The expected output is to produce a column with the similar string together with the score for each of the string as a new column. My question is quite fimiliar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405895/how-can-i-match-fuzzy-match-strings-from-two-datasets) question, it's just that the question is in R language and it used 2 datasets (mine is only 1). As I'm quite new to python, I'm quite confused how to do it.
I'm also have used a simple code with similar function however not so sure how to run it for the dataframe.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
def levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(s, t, ratio_calc = False):
    """ levenshtein_ratio_and_distance:
        Calculates levenshtein distance between two strings.
        If ratio_calc = True, the function computes the
        levenshtein distance ratio of similarity between two strings
        For all i and j, distance[i,j] will contain the Levenshtein
        distance between the first i characters of s and the
        first j characters of t
    """
    # Initialize matrix of zeros
    rows = len(s)+1
    cols = len(t)+1
    distance = np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype = int)

    # Populate matrix of zeros with the indeces of each character of both strings
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for k in range(1,cols):
            distance[i][0] = i
            distance[0][k] = k

    # Iterate over the matrix to compute the cost of deletions,insertions and/or substitutions    
    for col in range(1, cols):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if s[row-1] == t[col-1]:
                cost = 0 # If the characters are the same in the two strings in a given position [i,j] then the cost is 0
            else:
                # In order to align the results with those of the Python Levenshtein package, if we choose to calculate the ratio
                # the cost of a substitution is 2. If we calculate just distance, then the cost of a substitution is 1.
                if ratio_calc == True:
                    cost = 2
                else:
                    cost = 1
            distance[row][col] = min(distance[row-1][col] + 1,      # Cost of deletions
                                 distance[row][col-1] + 1,          # Cost of insertions
                                 distance[row-1][col-1] + cost)     # Cost of substitutions
    if ratio_calc == True:
        # Computation of the Levenshtein Distance Ratio
        Ratio = ((len(s)+len(t)) - distance[row][col]) / (len(s)+len(t))
        return Ratio
    else:
        # print(distance) # Uncomment if you want to see the matrix showing how the algorithm computes the cost of deletions,
        # insertions and/or substitutions
        # This is the minimum number of edits needed to convert string a to string b
        return "The strings are {} edits away".format(distance[row][col])

#example I do for simple string
    Str1 = "Apple Inc."
    Str2 = "Jo Inc"
    Distance = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1,Str2)
    print(Distance)
    Ratio = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1,Str2,ratio_calc = True)
    print(Ratio)
```

However, the code above only applicable for string. What is I want to run the dataframe as the input instead of string. For example, the input data is (Saying that **dataset name is customer**):

```
     name       
1    Ace Co
2    Ace Co.     
11   Baes 
4    Bayes Inc. 
8    Bayes 
12   Bays 
10   Bcy 
15   asd       
13    asd
```

The expected outcome is:

```
   name      b_name                       dist
   Ace Co    Ace Co.                      0.64762
   Baes      Bayes Inc., Bayes,Bays, Bcy  0.80000,0.86667,0.70000,0.97778
   asd       asdf                         0.08333
```

Comment: [`levenshtein`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.levenshtein) is included in spark directly.