# Using a dataframe as a regex reference to match string values

Tags: r, regex

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

I have a field named "ERROR_COLAB" in which a series of responses are concatenated into a single long string, because of  the nature of the ERRORS that can be present there is no a formal, objective, efficient way to "split" the values in  "ERROR_COLAB" to classify the responses concatenated in them.

So I was thinking about what if I can create a dataframe with the values that I need to extract to later on "parse" them into a regex formula in order to extract them.. to illustrate my idea:

Lets say I have this datedrame

| code_error | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| po_R83 | No_call_bak |
| ?OP | card_nofunds |
| HOTELARCH78 | overbookings |

and I have the following values in  "ERROR_COLAB"

| ERROR_COLAB |
| --- |
| ?OP_ERR7+JSU8.OIJK1 |
| po_R83_io |
| IOS_NEVER:300SSSS |
| HOTELARCH78?123- |

I would like to know if the **first part** of the string is equal to **any** of the values on the field "error code" of the dataframe containing the code and meanings . So my desired result would look like this:

| ERROR_COLAB | code_error_matched | meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ?OP_ERR7+JSU8.OIJK1 | ?OP | card_nofunds |
| po_R83_io | po_R83 | No_call_bak |
| IOS_NEVER:300SSSS | N.A | N.A |
| HOTELARCH78?123- | HOTELARCH78 | overbookings |

Thank you so much guys! like trully!

data:

```
codes<-tribble(~code_error, ~meaning,
"po_R83",   "No_call_bak",
"?OP",  "card_nofunds",
"HOTELARCH78",  "overbookings")

errors<-tribble(~ERROR,
"?OP_ERR7+JSU8.OIJK1",
"po_R83_io",
"IOS_NEVER:300SSSS",
"HOTELARCH78?123-")
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405895/how-can-i-match-fuzzy-match-strings-from-two-datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `agrep` + `merge`

```
merge(
  transform(
    codes,
    ERROR = sapply(code_error, function(x) agrep(x, errors$ERROR, value = TRUE))
  ),
  errors,
  all = TRUE
)
```

gives

```
                ERROR  code_error      meaning
1 ?OP_ERR7+JSU8.OIJK1         ?OP card_nofunds
2    HOTELARCH78?123- HOTELARCH78 overbookings
3   IOS_NEVER:300SSSS        <NA>         <NA>
4           po_R83_io      po_R83  No_call_bak
```