# match two vectors by similar characters/strings in R

Tags: r, string-matching, agrep

I have two vectors, like

```
v1<-c("yellow", "red", "orange", "blue", "green")
v2<-c("blues", "redx", "grean")
```

and I want to match them, i.e., to "link" each element of `v1` with the most similar element on `v2`, so that the result is

```
> df
      v1    v2
1 yellow  <NA>
2    red  redx
3 orange  <NA>
4   blue blues
5  green grean
```

The following code gives the expected result, but just because it has manually "formatted" to do so

```
df<-data.frame(v1,v2=rep(NA,5))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  ag<-agrep(df[i,1], v2, ignore.case = T, value = T)
  
  if (length(ag)==0) {df[i,2]<-NA}
  else if (length(ag)==1) {df[i,2]<-ag}
  else {df[i,2]<-ag[1]}
  
}
```

It happens that `agrep(df[2,1], v2, max.distance = 0.00001, ignore.case = T, value = T)` results in `"redx"  "grean"`, even if I set `max.distance = 0.00001`.

That's why I have the if conditions, but it doesn't guarantee that the most similar answer is selected.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405895/how-can-i-match-fuzzy-match-strings-from-two-datasets

Comment: Also see the "Note" on the `?agrep` help page. The function does not try to match entire strings. it tries to match substrings. Maybe you are looking for `adist()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
s <- which(adist(v1,v2) <= 1, TRUE) # 1 is the maximum allowed change
data.frame(v1, v2=replace(NA, s[,1], v2[s[,2]]))
      v1    v2
1 yellow  <NA>
2    red  redx
3 orange  <NA>
4   blue blues
5  green grean
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following can solve your problem. It uses `stringdistmatrix` in package `stringdist`, which can become a memory problem if the vectors `v1` and `v2` are larger.

```
d <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(v1, v2, method = "osa")
i <- which(colSums(d == 1) > 0)
j <- which(rowSums(d == 1) > 0)
df$v2[j] <- v2[i]

df
#      v1    v2
#1 yellow  <NA>
#2    red blues
#3 orange  <NA>
#4   blue  redx
#5  green grean
```