Join 2 data frames using grep
Consider the following, I have 2 data frames meta_df and data_df.
meta_df has an ID column, and data_df has another ID column which contains meta_df ID.
They can be created like this:
set.seed(123)
meta_df <- data.frame(id=paste0(sample(LETTERS,10,replace=F), sample(1:100,10,replace=F)),
                      response=c(rep('No',6),rep('Yes',4)), timepoint=c(rep(1:3,each=3),3))
data_df <- data.frame(id=paste(sample(1:10000000,30,replace=F),
                               sample(meta_df$id,30,replace=T),
                               sample(letters[1:5],30,replace=T), sep='_'),
                      value1=rnorm(30), value2=rnorm(30))

And look like this:
> meta_df
    id response timepoint
1  O91       No         1
2  S57       No         1
3  N92       No         1
4   C9       No         2
5  J93       No         2
6  R72       No         2
7  K26      Yes         3
8   E7      Yes         3
9  X42      Yes         3
10 Y97      Yes         3
> data_df
              id       value1      value2
1   5292587_C9_d  0.339956513  0.61097114
2  6705525_O91_d  0.596425059 -0.04786774
3   4924559R72_a  1.871418005 -2.39919771
4  2058730_N92_d  0.602870370 -0.01931896
5   7087879_E7_a -0.766168804 -0.08868545
6  8928169_N92_c -0.620326487 -1.59548490
7    4801559E7_d  0.790190251  0.85170932
8  3460231_O91_c -0.241976510 -0.71356081
9  3444635_K26_e  1.117486481  1.06643034
10 4678220_K26_d  1.184930635 -0.53624259
...

I just want to join them by ID. Originally I would do like the following (seeing as I was able to split by _):
id_split <- strsplit(data_df$id, "_")
data_df$id_full <- data_df$id
data_df$id <- sapply(id_split, "[", 2)
data_final <- dplyr::inner_join(data_df, meta_df, by="id")

And obtain this:
> data_final
    id       value1      value2       id_full response timepoint
1   C9  0.339956513  0.61097114  5292587_C9_d       No         2
2  O91  0.596425059 -0.04786774 6705525_O91_d       No         1
3  N92  0.602870370 -0.01931896 2058730_N92_d       No         1
4   E7 -0.766168804 -0.08868545  7087879_E7_a      Yes         3
5  N92 -0.620326487 -1.59548490 8928169_N92_c       No         1
6  O91 -0.241976510 -0.71356081 3460231_O91_c       No         1
7  K26  1.117486481  1.06643034 3444635_K26_e      Yes         3
8  K26  1.184930635 -0.53624259 4678220_K26_d      Yes         3
9  Y97  0.192996186 -1.82862663 1357263_Y97_d      Yes         3
10 R72 -0.392553554 -1.81353336 2652591_R72_a       No         2
...

... however, lately I have been given data sets where the _ is missing somewhere, or even with some of the info surrounding the true ID by _ missing altogether, or the ID itself not on position 2 between the _, etc, etc.
We can reproduce some of these cases like this:
data_df$id[c(3,7)] <- sub('_','',data_df$id[c(3,7)])
mysplit <- strsplit(data_df$id[c(15,28,30)],'_')
data_df$id[c(15,28,30)] <- paste0(sapply(mysplit, "[", 1), '_', sapply(mysplit, "[", 2), sapply(mysplit, "[", 3))
data_df$id[11] <- gsub('_','',data_df$id[11])
mysplit2 <- strsplit(data_df$id[c(9,23)],'_')
data_df$id[c(9,23)] <- paste0(sapply(mysplit2, "[", 2), '_', sapply(mysplit2, "[", 3))

As such, I cannot extract a rule, I just know that the true ID in meta_df is somewhere inside the ID in data_df... it could even be identical for some cases where all the surrounding info is missing.
How should I go about this? I just want to be able to join the 2 data frames by grep, if that is even possible.
Thanks!

Did you try fuzzy joins? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26405895/680068

If the id is always a capital letter followed by digits (regex "[A-Z]\\d+"), you could just extract that as a separate column for your join.

You can loop through each id in data_df and extract the matching id from meta_df.
meta_df <- data.frame(id=paste0(sample(LETTERS,10,replace=F), sample(1:100,10,replace=F)),
                      response=c(rep('No',6),rep('Yes',4)), timepoint=c(rep(1:3,each=3),3))

data_df <- data.frame(id=paste(sample(1:10000000,30,replace=F),
                               sample(meta_df$id,30,replace=T),
                               sample(letters[1:5],30,replace=T), sep='_'),
                      value1=rnorm(30), value2=rnorm(30))

id_extracted <- NULL

for (id in data_df$id) {
  id_extracted <- c(id_extracted, meta_df$id[stringr::str_detect(id, meta_df$id)])
}

data_df$id_extracted <- id_extracted

Then you can join on your new column
> dplyr::left_join(data_df, meta_df, by = c("id_extracted" = "id"))

              id       value1      value2 id_extracted response timepoint
1   5292587_C9_d  0.339956513  0.61097114           C9       No         2
2  6705525_O91_d  0.596425059 -0.04786774          O91       No         1
3  4924559_R72_a  1.871418005 -2.39919771          R72       No         2
4  2058730_N92_d  0.602870370 -0.01931896          N92       No         1
5   7087879_E7_a -0.766168804 -0.08868545           E7      Yes         3

This assumes that every one of data_df$id actually contains one of meta_df$id - you will have to fiddle about some more if this is not necessarily the case.
